# Is there a limit to the amount of data that can be Run?

Tags: graphics, command-line, svg-format, run

I need this command to work through the WolframKernel and it seems well beyond my understanding why it does not work above a certain amount of data size I'm passing to `Run`

```
show[g_]:=Run["LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin;
   echo'<>StringReplace[ExportString[g,"SVG"],"\n"->" "]<>"'|bcat -b firefox &"]
```

It requires bcat (`apt-get ruby-bcat`) and it opens a new Firefox tab.

For simple graphics there're no issues. But, if I create a big SVG string the shell returns with error `32512`. It's like the WolframKernel does not like to pass long commands to the shell. As a matter of fact, by exporting the same big SVG string+bash syntax to a shell executable, it runs just fine.

For instance, `RandomGraph[{100,100}]` is already too big to be evaluated by the `show` function.

Comment: A workaround might be to export to a file and then read that file into `bcat`.

Comment: @CarlLange that's what I meant with "As a matter of fact, by exporting the same big SVG string+bash syntax to a shell executable, it runs just fine. "

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that. `ExportString[RandomGraph[{100, 100}], "SVG"]` is nearly 0.1 MB in size - I don't know what the issue is but it wouldn't shock me greatly to find that there's a bottleneck somewhere. Pasting 95000 characters into a terminal might break too.